# Error code on my while loop, trying to read line by line through a file. in C

Tags: c, file, while-loop, hashtable

I am trying to take input from the file dictionary, one line at a time, I know each line in the file dictionary is just one word. I am getting an error code when I try to compile this code and here the error is :

dictionary.c:66:36: error: comparison of distinct pointer types ('char *' and 'int (*)(FILE *)')
      [-Werror,-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
    while ( (fgets(word, 46, dic)) != feof )

I am very new to coding, and am not sure if this can be done this way, if I am trying to use the wrong method or if I am just coding this incorrectly. Thank you for nay help in advance.

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    char word[46];
    unsigned long key;

    //remember file name
    FILE* dic = fopen(dictionary , "r");
    if (dic == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file..\n");
            return false;
        }
    while ( (fgets(word, 46, dic)) != feof )
        {
            numberWords++;
            //Save new word
            node* newWord = malloc(sizeof(node));
            strcpy(newWord->dicWords, word);
            newWord->next = NULL;
            //Use Hash function on new word found
            key = hash(word);
            //Enter word into Hashtable
            if ( hashTable[key] == NULL )
                {
                    hashTable[key] = newWord;
                }
            else
                {
                    newWord->next = hashTable[key];
                    hashTable[key] = newWord;
                }
        }

    fclose(dic);

    return false;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `fgets` retains a `newline` at the end of each input. You can remove it with this line: `word [ strcspn(word, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feof` is the identifier of a library function. Please change

```
while ( (fgets(word, 46, dic)) != feof )
```

to

```
while ( (fgets(word, 46, dic)) != NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

You get it because you compare the result of `fgets` against the *function* `feof`. You probably meant to write `feof(fp)` or perhaps `EOF`.

Which is also wrong, since `fgets` return NULL upon errors.